# Zip file app/build/intermediates/app_classes/release/classes.jar' already contains entry 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF', cannot overwrite

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When building my Android app with Android-Studio in debug, it works, but when building in release mode, I get the following error at the `:app:bundleReleaseClasses` step:

```
Zip file app/build/intermediates/app_classes/release/classes.jar' already contains entry 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF', cannot overwrite
```

Building in CLI with `./gradlew assembleDebug` (or even `./gradlew bundleReleaseClasses`) works.

What could be the reason for this error in Android-Studio, knowing that it works in gradle CLI? I tried excluding this file in `packagingOptions {}`, but it does not seem to have any effect.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439933/classes-jar-already-contains-entry-meta-inf-module-name-debug-kotlin-module), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787269/gradle-duplicate-entry-error-meta-inf-manifest-mf-or-how-to-delete-a-file-from), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626654/buildprebundle-failed-duplicate-entry-meta-inf-manifest-mf), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387854/entry-name-meta-inf-manifest-mf-collided-when-building-for-api-21-emulator-as) and a few other related questions, but did not find an answer.

Note that it fails with AGP 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3 and 7.0.4. Not sure if I should try going further back.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Comment: It disappeared, I could not identify what changed. Some update of some subcomponent probably, as mentioned by the answer below. I would just try to update the gradle plugin, gradle, and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in debug build, and I fixed it by deleting `Build` folder.

```
already contains entry 'META-INF/xxxxxx_debug.kotlin_module', cannot overwrite
```

1. Go to project view -> Build (delete this folder)
2. Rebuild (Build -> Rebuild Project)

Answer (score -2):

Just Update your Gradle plugin version version

I had the same error in Android Studio Chipmunk| 2021.2.1 and Gradle version 7.1.2
and after updating Gradle plugin version to 7.2.0 this problem is resolved.

Comment: I would like to have answer analyzing the root cause and then suggesting a solution. This sort of an answer is not helpful.